# Cauchy sequence!

Tags: real-analysis

I have 2 questions about Cauchy sequence:\

1) Let $\left\{a_n\right\}$ be a sequence such that $\vert a_n-a_{n+1}\vert \le \frac{\vert a_{n-1}-a_n\vert}{ 2}$. Prove that $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

2) Prove or provide a counter example: If $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then for $n$ and $m$ large enough it holds $\vert a_{n+1}-a_{m+1}\vert \le \vert a_n - a_m \vert$.

For the first question, I set $b_n = a_n - a_{n+1}$ and proved that $b_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, then $a_n$ is a Pseudo _ Cauchy sequence. But the fact is that a Pseudo_Cauchy sequence might not be a Cauchy sequence. I don't know what happen with my proof.
For the second question, I don't have a hint about this.
Hope you can help me out. Thank you.

Comment: What is a pseudo-Cauchy sequence?

Comment: The pseudo-Cauchy sequence's definition : $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \ge N$ , it implies that $\vert a_{n+1}-a_n \vert < \epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

No idea what a pseudo-Cauchy sequence is, but for 1, we have $$ a_m-a_n = (a_{n+1}-a_n) + (a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})+\ldots+(a_m-a_{m-1})$$ for $m>n$ so $$ |a_m-a_n| \le |a_{n+1}-a_n| \left(1 + \frac{1}{2}+\ldots \frac{1}{2^{m-n-1}}\right) <2|a_{n+1}-a_n|.$$

For 2, let the sequence be $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ even and $0$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much. I checked it but with the pseudo-Cauchy sequence's definition is : ∀ϵ>0, ∃N∈N such that ∀n≥N , it implies that |an+1−an|<ϵ . And take $\left\{a_n\right\} = \sqrt{n}$, it is a pseudo-Cauchy sequence, but it is not a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @user386505 Well, if you've proven that, then my hint becomes a solution pretty quickly

Answer (score 2):

(1) Note that from $|a_n-a_{n+1}|\leq 2^{-1}|a_{n-1}-a_n|$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ it follows that
\begin{align*}
|a_n-a_{n+1}|\leq 2^{-n}|a_0-a_1|.
\end{align*}
For $n>m$ it then follows that
\begin{align*}
|a_n-a_m|\leq\sum_{j=m}^{n-1}|a_{j+1}-a_j|\leq|a_0-a_1|\sum_{j=m}^{n-1}2^{-j}\leq2|a_0-a_1|(2^{-m}-2^{-n}),
\end{align*}
which goes to 0 as $m,n\to\infty$.

(2) Consider $a_n=0$ for even $n$ and $a_n=1/n$ for odd $n$. Then $(a_n)$ converges to 0 and is hence a Cauchy-sequence (in $\mathbb R$), but for distinct even $m,n$ we have $|a_{n+1}-a_{m+1}|=|1/(n+1)-1/(m+1)|>0=|a_n-a_m|$.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask again.